# How to format monolingual text type SMW properties so accessible to queries without duplication

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I'm trying to mark up inline text as being of a specific language.

I've created a `Property::Has language` page with `[[Has type::Monolingual text]]`.

But when I add `[[Has language::(some text)@eo| ]]`, if "(some text)" is too long of a blob, the page reports an error.

When I instead take the approach of avoiding marking up any text, and go with just `[[Has language::@eo| ]]`, I can't get the `Special:Ask` query page to work with a query of `[[Has language::@eo]]` or `[[Has language::+]]`, I guess because the [monolingual text type](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Type_Monolingual_text) strips out the `@eo`. (And although querying the built-in type `[[Language code::eo]]` works, this will apply to any Monolingual text type property.)

I worked around this problem by adding `[[Has language::eo@eo| ]]`, allowing at least queries for `[[Has language::eo]]` to work, but this duplication is a bit annoying (and also gives the false impression to "eo" is text in the "eo" language), and it of course only allows searching for the presence of the "eo" language rather than being able to find specific content in the "eo" language.

Is there a better way to mark this up that ideally avoids running afoul of length limits or if not, at least avoids duplication in markup to test language presence?

Comment: You might want to file an SMW issue for this even if it's potentially only a question. Then link back from the issue to this question.